# HTTP1.1 is timing out on some urls

Tags: npm, curl, timeout, node-fetch, http-1.1

I am using npm module `node-fetch` to call online shop URLs; some are timing out.

This happens when the call is made with `http1.1` which is used in most API npm modules such as `node-fetch`. Can someone help me to understand how to make a call with `http1.1` and get a response back for following examples:

```
curl -m 10 -v --http1.1 "https://www.dhgate.com" \
-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" \
-H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.98" \
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" \
-H "Connection: keep-alive" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

or

```
curl -m 10 -v --http1.1 "https://www.abercrombie.com/shop/us" \
-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" \
-H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.98" \
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" \
-H "Connection: keep-alive" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

In `node-fetch` I tuned on debugging which is printing logs from `http` npm module by `NODE_DEBUG=http,net,stream` and here are logs, perhaps it's helpful for troubleshooting:

```
HTTP 67536: createConnection www.dhgate.com:443::::::::::::::::::::: [Object: null prototype] {
  protocol: 'https:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'www.dhgate.com',
  port: 443,
  hostname: 'www.dhgate.com',
  hash: null,
  search: '?wgu=8477_127107_16977422063155_b7229050b9&wgexpiry=1729278206&f=bm%7Caff%7Cwg%7C55163%7C8477_127107_16977422063155_b7229050b9%7C0%7C%7C%7Cus%7C%7C%7C&utm_source=webgains_us&utm_medium=Affiliate&utm_content=0&utm_campaign=affid',
  query: 'wgu=8477_127107_16977422063155_b7229050b9&wgexpiry=1729278206&f=bm%7Caff%7Cwg%7C55163%7C8477_127107_16977422063155_b7229050b9%7C0%7C%7C%7Cus%7C%7C%7C&utm_source=webgains_us&utm_medium=Affiliate&utm_content=0&utm_campaign=affid',
  pathname: '/product/fashion-women-sandals-summer-flats-sexy-ankle/479784035.html',
  path: null,
  href: 'https://www.dhgate.com/product/fashion-women-sandals-summer-flats-sexy-ankle/479784035.html?wgu=8477_127107_16977422063155_b7229050b9&wgexpiry=1729278206&f=bm%7Caff%7Cwg%7C55163%7C8477_127107_16977422063155_b7229050b9%7C0%7C%7C%7Cus%7C%7C%7C&utm_source=webgains_us&utm_medium=Affiliate&utm_content=0&utm_campaign=affid',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: [Object: null prototype] {
    Accept: [
      'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.98'
    ],
    'Accept-Encoding': [ 'gzip, deflate, br' ],
    Connection: [ 'keep-alive' ],
    'User-Agent': [
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    ],
    'Content-Type': [ 'application/json' ]
  },
  agent: undefined,
  _defaultAgent: Agent {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      free: [Function (anonymous)],
      newListener: [Function: maybeEnableKeylog]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    defaultPort: 443,
    protocol: 'https:',
    options: [Object: null prototype] {
      keepAlive: true,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      timeout: 5000,
      noDelay: true,
      path: null
    },
    requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
    sockets: [Object: null prototype] {
      'www.dhgate.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::': []
    },
    freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {
      'track.webgains.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::': [Array]
    },
    keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
    keepAlive: true,
    maxSockets: Infinity,
    maxFreeSockets: 256,
    scheduling: 'lifo',
    maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
    totalSocketCount: 1,
    maxCachedSessions: 100,
    _sessionCache: { map: [Object], list: [Array] },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  keepAlive: true,
  scheduling: 'lifo',
  timeout: 5000,
  noDelay: true,
  servername: 'www.dhgate.com',
  _agentKey: 'www.dhgate.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::'
}
NET 67536: pipe false null
NET 67536: connect: find host www.dhgate.com
NET 67536: connect: dns options { family: undefined, hints: 1024 }
NET 67536: connect: autodetecting
HTTP 67536: sockets www.dhgate.com:443::::::::::::::::::::: 1 2
HTTP 67536: outgoing message end.
STREAM 67536: read 0
STREAM 67536: need readable false
STREAM 67536: length less than watermark true
STREAM 67536: do read
NET 67536: _read - n 16384 isConnecting? true hasHandle? true
NET 67536: _read wait for connection
STREAM 67536: resume
STREAM 67536: resume true
STREAM 67536: flow true
STREAM 67536: read undefined
STREAM 67536: need readable true
STREAM 67536: length less than watermark true
STREAM 67536: reading, ended or constructing false
NET 67536: connect/multiple: only one address found, switching back to single connection
NET 67536: connect: attempting to connect to 23.44.84.179:443 (addressType: 4)
NET 67536: afterConnect
NET 67536: _read - n 16384 isConnecting? false hasHandle? true
NET 67536: Socket._handle.readStart
STREAM 67536: read 0
STREAM 67536: need readable true
STREAM 67536: length less than watermark true
STREAM 67536: reading, ended or constructing false
STREAM 67536: onWriteComplete 0 undefined
NET 67536: _onTimeout
HTTP 67536: CLIENT socket onTimeout
NET 67536: destroy
NET 67536: close
NET 67536: close handle
NET 67536: emit close
HTTP 67536: CLIENT socket onClose
HTTP 67536: removeSocket track.webgains.com:443::::::::::::::::::::: writable: false
NET 67536: _onTimeout
HTTP 67536: CLIENT socket onTimeout
STREAM 67536: readableAddChunk null
STREAM 67536: onEofChunk
STREAM 67536: emitReadable_ false 0 true
STREAM 67536: flow true
STREAM 67536: read undefined
STREAM 67536: endReadable false
STREAM 67536: read 0
STREAM 67536: endReadable false
STREAM 67536: endReadableNT false 0
STREAM 67536: endReadableNT true 0
NET 67536: _final: not ended, call shutdown()
NET 67536: afterShutdown destroyed=false
NET 67536: destroy
NET 67536: close
NET 67536: close handle
NET 67536: emit close
HTTP 67536: CLIENT socket onClose
```